# remove last space from string react native”

Tags: javascript, react-native

I´m trying to remove the last space (uf there is one) on the string derived from a Textinput

i have to allow spaces between characters something like "Maria de jesus". but if there a space at the end of the string it has to be erased, also I cant allow non numeric characters.

this is what i have

```
<TextInput
              style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Nombre*"
              placeholderTextColor={theme.SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCompleteType="off"
              autoCapitalize="characters"
              onChangeText={
              (() => setvName(values.fName), handleChange('fName'))
            }
              onFocus={() => setvTip(true)}
              onBlur= {() => {setvName(values.fName.trimEnd()); handleBlur('fName');  setvTip(false)}}
              textTransform= 'uppercase'
             value={values.fName.replace(/[^A-Za-z\s+|\s+$ ]/ig, '')}
            />
```

I have tried with replace, trim() and trimEnd()
the result of those tries where that it didnt let me put spaces and keep writing since it erase any space i write

any thoughts?

Comment: Should work just with the onBlur , no?

Comment: it should, but for some reason it doesnt

Comment: Create a demo that demonstrates the problem

Comment: You can probably sanitize the string at the end. Not in the `onChange` but when the user sends the input data to the server. In your `onSubmit` function. If that's your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `trimEnd()` on the input value before you send the data with the API call.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd